# Filter laravel one condition controller

Tags: laravel, filter

Here is my page:

[image]

Needs filter only the result "viagem" in column `status_viagem`.

My controller:

```
public function listaPainel(Request $request)
{
    $lista = Cco::all();
    $data['lista'] = $lista; 
    return view('rast.lista_painel', $data);
}
```

Comment: $lista = Cco::where('status_viagem','viagem')->get();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple [where](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#basic-where-clauses) will do that:

```
$lista = Cco::where('status_viagem','=','VIAGEM')->get();
```